# Wrong display format for .doc

Tags: c#, ms-word

basically i would like to display .doc file in WWW, i've tried to fetch data by code below
i can fetch data from .doc but the output is not expected format.

**data inside .doc**

> A
>
> B
>
> C

**output result**

> A B C

**my expected result is**

> A
>
> B
>
> C

protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass();

        // File Path

        string strFilePath = @"C:\Users\Roy\Desktop\fypdoc.doc";

        // Create obj filename to pass it as paremeter in open 
        object objFile = strFilePath; object objNull = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

        object objReadOnly = true;//Open Document
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document Doc = wordApp.Documents.Open(ref objFile, ref objNull, ref objReadOnly, ref objNull, ref objNull, ref objNull, ref objNull, ref objNull, ref objNull, ref objNull, ref objNull, ref objNull, ref objNull, ref objNull, ref objNull, ref objNull);

        // To read each line consider each line as paragraph Docuemnt

        int i = 1;

        foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Paragraph objParagraph in Doc.Paragraphs)
        {

            try
            {
               p1.InnerHtml += Doc.Paragraphs[i].Range.Text.Replace(Environment.NewLine,"</br>");

          }
            catch (Exception ex) { throw ex; } i++;

        } // close document and Quit Word ApplicationDoc.Close(ref objNull, ref objNull, ref objNull);

        wordApp.Quit(ref objNull, ref objNull, ref objNull);

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using line breaks, try to preserve the semantic value of paragraphs:

```
p1.InnerHtml += "<p>" + Doc.Paragraphs[i].Range.Text + "</p>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `</br>` with `<br />`.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem here is that you're reading in 3 paragraphs and yet not adding adding lines between them when transferring them to your html.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are looping through each Paragraph, and if you are expecting each paragraph to be a block of text seperated by linebreaks then they won't contain any line breaks themselves.

Either add the br after concatenating your text or use Paragraph tags.